# Git: A feature branch is showing up in master branch when I didn't merge them

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to find how it got merged into the main branch?

I can't find it in my git reflog or git log, only commits to origin/feature_branch_name, but somehow it's also in origin/main_branch_name.

I create my branches with

```
git checkout -b feature_branch_name
```

I pushed my branch to origin with

```
git push origin feature_branch_name
```

and git's output was

```
<hash1>..<hash2> feature_branch_name -> feature_branch_name
```

The next day, I checked out our main branch and pulled, and some new files showed up in the main branch when I pulled.  Any ideas how I can track this down?

Comment: *checked out our main branch and pulled* - so you have pulled into master branch

Comment: Yes, I was on master_branch_name and did a "git pull", at which point my updates on feature_branch_name were in master_branch_name

Comment: So, there were specific commits on the feature branch that were merged into your master branch? Do you work on this project with anyone? You can look in the log, but if it was a fast forward merge there will not be a merge commit, so you'd have to check with your collaborators.

Comment: Yes, all commits on the feature branch were merged into the master branch, and only my commits show up when I look through the log... so I'd have to talk to people? Blah.

Comment: Are you using GitHub or any remote hosting service for your repository? _MAYBE_ it was in a PR, otherwise I think you'd have to talk to someone. Sorry.

Comment: I think you were right the first time, actually.  I think someone FF-merged my feature branch into another branch, which eventually ended up back in the main branch.  I was able to use git log --ancestry-path to view the ancestry back to mine, but you can't see any of the files I presume because they were fast forward-merged

Answer (score 3):

to find which commits (created/modified/destroyed) a certain file:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --all -- THE_NEW_FILE
```

this displays the first line of the commit message, and any associated branches/tags.

to view the changes introduced by a commit

```
git whatchanged -1 COMMIT_HASH
or
git diff --stat COMMIT_HASH~ COMMIT_HASH
```

you reflog only records where your HEAD and branch heads have been, not what other users have done.   To see an overview of the recent history of the commit chain for your current branch.

```
git log --oneline -32
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need, but thanks.  I know what commits created the files; I created them.  I don't know how my_feature_branch got into main_branch.  So far "git log my_parent_branch ^my_feature_branch --ancestry-path" is close, but still not quite what I need.